# webclient uri formats are not supported

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0

```
WebClient fileReader = new WebClient();
fileAddress = listItem;    

//error here uri formats are not supported
fileReader.DownloadFile(fileAddress, saveTo);
```

here in fileaddress address coming

```
http://pcdev04.pcsolution.net:83\Update32\rts\RTSUpdate.dll
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace `\` with `/` in your URI string in order to have a valid address:

```
fileReader.DownloadFile(fileAddress.Replace("\\", "/"), saveTo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `WebClient` Class to open File on internet 
Take a look at this - [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24920/C-Image-Download) 
Opens and download image file.

hope it helps